# Why does firebug disappear on page refresh?

Tags: firebug, firefox4

Hope I can get some help here.

I am using latest version of firefox and firebug. I want to watch network activity when I reload a page and view my site. But as soon as I reload then firebug disappears. Is there a way to pin it. Why does it go from view.

Maricel

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you're asking how to keep the Net Panel from being cleared when the page is refreshed or reloaded.

You should see a `Persist` option on the Net Panel toolbar - enable it to persist the data across page reloads.

[image: Firebug Net Panel Persist Across Page Reloads]

---

If the problem really is that Firebug just disappears then the cause might be one of the following:

1. Firefox's "Never Remember History" (under `Tools > Options > Privacy`) - tracking history should be enabled. This is equivalent to "Private Browsing" mode and so if you're in that mode, you'll see the same problem.
2. Firebug extensions can cause issues - for example, an older version of Firecookie.
3. If the page URL changes, then you'll need to make sure that Firebug is enabled for all pages.

References:

- https://groups.google.com/group/firebug/browse_thread/thread/035a04988be24b3f
- https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=2047
- https://groups.google.com/group/firebug/browse_thread/thread/18bb6f58f329c176
- https://groups.google.com/group/firebug/browse_thread/thread/e0e3de62f7750aa4
- https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=3724